# Exclude file storage from VMWare snapshots?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

Say we have a Windows Server 2008 with the role of a file server, and 500GB of files on the D drive. Files are backup up to tape.  How is it possible to take a snapshot of the OS without the file on the D drive (or delta) being included in the VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure the virtual hard disk as 'Independent', in 'Persistent' mode.

This will prevent the disk from being affected in any way when a snapshot is taken or reverted; if you revert a snapshot, you will not revert the Independent disk.

Comment: Thanks, first time user here.  You saved us a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your disk to be 'independent'. When the disk is added, or when the VM is down, right click the VM - > Edit settings. Select the disk and the option to make it independent and persistant is there on the right. Any independent disk wont be snapshotted.